# ASP.NET CORE Web API Serilog and ElasticSearch logging not working on IIS but works locally

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog

I configured .NET 5 Web API Serilog and Elasticsearch, it works normally on local when run application and send request from REST client. But when i publish it on IIS and made same request to same endpoints it is not working entirely. No any logs from app published on IIS.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureLogging();
            
            CreateHost(args);
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseWebRoot("client-app");
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                    configuration.AddJsonFile(
                        $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                        optional: true);
                })
                .UseSerilog();

        private static void ConfigureLogging()
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile(
                    $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                    optional: true)
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(configuration, environment))
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", environment)
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        private static ElasticsearchSinkOptions ConfigureElasticSink(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string environment)
        {
            return new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
            {
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{environment?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}"
            };
        }

        private static void CreateHost(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal($"Failed to start {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Elastic uri has not restriction on IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29EhV.png)

[image: appsetting.json file]

Comment: Maybe i am overlooking some configs related on production mode of app

Comment: always try using elastic on https and include login credentials